# RDLC Report Viewer size is not set properly

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting

I have created an RDLC Report with multiple DataSources. (As a Choose the Data source in User Requirement based on value selecting in a dropdown list). All the Reports are generating correctly. But the problem is the Report size (based on .RDLC file) does not show based on what is set in the .RDLC file.

Help me. My reports are given below:

- My first Report Data Sources Report will generate with correct Width and Height that I am giving.
- 2nd Report Data Source for the same report viewer, but the size of report (.rdlc file) is not set.
- 3rd one. Here also same Report Viewer but the size of report is not correct.

Comment: By "size" do you mean the physical report page output size? You are going to need to provide more details on what setting you have used (etc.) in order for us to help.

Comment: I agree with robnick. We are definitely going to need more information on the issue you are having before we can help.